# Javascript game problems

Tags: javascript

So i am making a simple Rock, Paper, Scissors game. But when I run it. It doesn't gave the output I am looking for. It might be a simple mistake but any help would be appreciated.

````
var Rock = 1;
var Paper = 2;
var Scissors = 3;
const answer = prompt("Do you want to play Rock Paper Scissors? Type yes or no!");
if ( answer.toUpperCase() === 'YES') {
  alert("You will need to type your response!")
  let answer = prompt("Rock, Paper, or Scissors?");
  const dieRoll = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1;
  alert(`The Creator rolled a ${dieRoll}.`);
} else {
  alert("Well bye then!!")
window.location.href = '../index.html';
}
if ( answer.toUpperCase() === 'ROCK', 'PAPER', 'SCISSORS' > dieRoll ) {
  alert("You win!")
} else {
  alert("You Lose!")
}```
````

Comment: There is a special place in hell for people who downvote without commenting on why they downvoted (especially to a new contributor). I'm checking your code, can you be a bit more specific on which part is working differently than you expected? (edit the question)

Comment: Hi thanks for commenting back. Not to sure about the "hell for people part" But I am new to stack flow. So the part were it says "if ( answer.toUpperCase() === 'ROCK', 'PAPER', 'SCISSORS' > dieRoll )" doesn't run. I can run it up to the part with the creator rolls the dice. But doesn't give me the response i want. Once i can figure it out. I was going to change to Number output tpo Rock, Paper, Scissors. PS var Rock = 1; seems to have got chopped out in the top.

Comment: (Some people downvoted your question without expalining why the downvote.) In javascript you cannot compare to a number of items like that. You have to compare like `if(answer.toUpperCase() === 'ROCK' || answer.toUpperCase() === 'PAPER' ||  answer.toUpperCase() === 'PAPER'){}`. Also comparing if that is greater than `dieRoll` is suspicious, not sure what that would mean.

Comment: Well that fixed my response problem. Now i just need to tweak it. Thank you. And for the dieRoll i was trying to get it to produce a result. Like if the person typed rock which is a value of 1 and compare it to the dice roll. So if "1 > 2"  then it will produce you lose and vice versa. Still tweaking it.

Comment: OK. I think that only complicates your logic beyond understanding. I would personally make 3 IFs each of them having another 3 IFs to cover all combinations.

Answer (score 2):

Its missing some game logic and syntax is slightly wrong, id rewrite it so it is more verbose, like the following.

```js
const tolowerUcFirst = v => v.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + v.slice(1).toLowerCase()

const answer = prompt(
  'Do you want to play Rock Paper Scissors? Type yes or no!'
)

if (answer && ['Y', 'YES'].includes(answer.toUpperCase())) {
  let board = ['ROCK', 'PAPER', 'SCISSORS']
  let answer = prompt('Rock, Paper, or Scissors?')

  if (board.includes(answer.toUpperCase())) {
    let them = board[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]
    let you = answer.toUpperCase()

    if (them === you) {
      console.log('draw', you, them)
      alert(`Draw, they choose ${tolowerUcFirst(them)} too!`)
    } else {
      // win rules
      if (
        // SCISSORS
        (you === 'SCISSORS' && them === 'PAPER') ||
        // PAPER
        (you === 'PAPER' && them === 'ROCK') ||
        // ROCK
        (you === 'ROCK' && them === 'SCISSORS')
      ) {
        console.log('you win', you, them)
        alert(`You win, they choose ${tolowerUcFirst(them)}!`)
      } else {
        console.log('you lose', you, them)
        alert(`You lose, they choose ${tolowerUcFirst(them)}!`)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well it doesn't show the results for picking R,P,S. But I do appreciate it. Ill compare your code to mines and see what I can tweak around. PS I am very new to coding and the only training i had was through treehouse.

Comment: np, if it helped, upvote and/or accept