# prompt keep popping up even though I write the write answer

Tags: javascript

I have a question why this is happening, I want when the user doesn't type one of the values
the prompt keeps popping up until the user type one, what is happening here is that it keep popping up even tho I'm typing one of the possibilities.

```
const player = document.querySelector(".player");
const computer = document.querySelector(".computer");
const button = document.querySelector("button");
let choose;
button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  choose = prompt(`Please choose between Rock, paper, scissors`).toUpperCase();
  if (choose === "ROCK") {
    console.log("ROCK");
  } else if (choose === "PAPER") {
    console.log("PAPER");
  } else if (choose === "SCISSORS") {
    console.log("SCISSORS");
  } else {
    while (choose !== "ROCK" || choose !== "PAPER" || choose !== "SCISSORS") {
      choose = prompt(
        `Please choose between Rock, paper, scissors`
      ).toUpperCase();
    }
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: remove it from the while loop

Comment: see: [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62267495/javascript-game-problems/62268167#62268167)

Comment: Thanks for replying, I already did, but it keeps popping up (which I want but even when I type the right answer )

Comment: ok, then do `while (!["ROCK", "PAPER", "SCISSORS"].includes(choose))`

Comment: It worked but something I noticed when I retype ROCK || PAPER ..., the console.log doesn't show, so in advance the syntax in the if and else if will not work..

Comment: it wont jump back up and check the if statements again.. to do that abstract the *ask* loop into a function and only continue if once get the satisfactory choice, then do the ifs

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean to say:

```
while (choose !== "ROCK" && choose !== "PAPER" && choose !== "SCISSORS") {
...
}
```

As `choose` will always not equal at least 2 of them.

EDIT: You could simplify your code to:

```
const player = document.querySelector(".player");
const computer = document.querySelector(".computer");
const button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let choose;
  while (choose !== "ROCK" && choose !== "PAPER" && choose !== "SCISSORS") {
    choose = prompt(`Please choose between Rock, paper, scissors`).toUpperCase();
  }
  if (choose === "ROCK") {
    console.log("ROCK");
  } else if (choose === "PAPER") {
    console.log("PAPER");
  } else if (choose === "SCISSORS") {
    console.log("SCISSORS");
  }
});
```

Comment: It worked yes Sir, but the same issue, the console.log doesn't show, so in advance the syntax in the if and else it will not work.

Comment: I've edited my answer to give an example of how to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you can contain the prompt within one while loop

```
button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let choose;
  do {
    choose = prompt(`Please choose between Rock, paper, scissors`).toUpperCase();
  } while (!["ROCK","PAPER","SCISSORS"].includes(choose));
  console.log(choose); // one of ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much